# Probability of drawing a ball in sequence without replacing

Tags: probability, probability-theory

### My Question

> $\text{In a box,there are $2$ red,$3$ black and $4$ blue coloured balls.
> The probability of drawing }$
>   $2\text{ blue balls in sequence without replacing and then
> drawing $1$ black ball from this box is} $

### My Approach

Reqd probability$$=\frac{\binom{4}{2} \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}}$$

$$=\frac{3}{14}=21.4 \% $$
but the answer is given as $\text{6.80 to 7.20(Range)} \%$
Am i doing it right ?Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: The order is specified.  So:  $\frac 4{9}\times \frac 38\times \frac 37$.  Your computation gives the probability of drawing $2$ blue and $1$ black in any order, so three times the correct answer.

Comment: We could modify your approach:  The probability that the first two balls are blue is $\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}}$.  The probability that the third ball selected is black given that two blue balls have already been selected is $\frac{\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{7}{1}}$ since three of the seven balls remaining are black.  Hence, the required probability is $$\Pr(\text{two blue, then one black}) = \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{7}{1}} = \frac{1}{14}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks a lot.This was the point i was looking for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to draw them in an exact order, so it should be:

$$\frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{3}{7}$$

... I am wondering ... why is the answer stated as a range?

Comment: if the question is **with replacement** then my approach is correct?

Comment: @laura No ... you have calculated the probability of picking 2 blue and 1 black balls as a set out of the $9$ ... which is equivalent to picking $3$ balls *without* replacement ... but that would be compatible with first drawing a black and then 2 blue ones.  But it is specified that the *third* one should be black. Also, if the problem was stated as If it was *with* replacement, it would be $\frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{3}{9}$